# SPARQL Query returns 0

Tags: sparql

i´ve this individuals in my ontology:

```
 <!-- http://127.0.0.1/Public_Contracting.owl#CPV1 -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&Public_Contracting;CPV1">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&Public_Contracting;CPV"/>
    <isCPVOf rdf:resource="&Public_Contracting;Procedure_1"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>


<!-- http://127.0.0.1/Public_Contracting.owl#CPV2 -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&Public_Contracting;CPV2">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&Public_Contracting;CPV"/>
    <isCPVOf rdf:resource="&Public_Contracting;Procedure_2"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>


<!-- http://127.0.0.1/Public_Contracting.owl#Procedure_1 -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&Public_Contracting;Procedure_1">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&Public_Contracting;Procedure"/>
    <hasCPV rdf:resource="&Public_Contracting;CPV1"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>


<!-- http://127.0.0.1/Public_Contracting.owl#Procedure_2 -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&Public_Contracting;Procedure_2">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&Public_Contracting;Procedure"/>
    <hasCPV rdf:resource="&Public_Contracting;CPV2"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

And i´m trying to retrieve all procedures that contain CPV1.

How can i do it with SPARQL?

I tried this:

```
PREFIX ns: <http://127.0.0.1/Public_Contracting.owl#>
SELECT ?proc 
WHERE {
    ?proc a ns:Procedure ; 
          ns:hasCPV ?cpv.
    ?cpv ns:CPV ?cpvp 
    FILTER regex (?cpvp, "^CPV1")
}
```

but i get no results.

This is my ontology:

```
<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
<!ENTITY owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" >
<!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
<!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
<!ENTITY Public_Contracting "http://127.0.0.1/Public_Contracting.owl#" >
<!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >]>


<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://127.0.0.1/Public_Contracting.owl#"
     xml:base="http://127.0.0.1/Public_Contracting.owl"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:Public_Contracting="http://127.0.0.1/Public_Contracting.owl#"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#">
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://127.0.0.1/Public_Contracting.owl"/>


<!-- http://127.0.0.1/Public_Contracting.owl#Procedure -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="&Public_Contracting;Procedure">
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&Public_Contracting;hasSupplier"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="&Public_Contracting;Supplier"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&Public_Contracting;hasBuyer"/>
                <owl:onClass rdf:resource="&Public_Contracting;Buyer"/>
                <owl:qualifiedCardinality rdf:datatype="&xsd;nonNegativeInteger">1</owl:qualifiedCardinality>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&Public_Contracting;hasProposal"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="&Public_Contracting;Proposal"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&Public_Contracting;hasProcedureTeam"/>
                <owl:onClass rdf:resource="&Public_Contracting;Procedure_Team"/>
                <owl:qualifiedCardinality rdf:datatype="&xsd;nonNegativeInteger">1</owl:qualifiedCardinality>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&Public_Contracting;hasStatus"/>
                <owl:onClass rdf:resource="&Public_Contracting;Procedure_Status"/>
                <owl:qualifiedCardinality rdf:datatype="&xsd;nonNegativeInteger">1</owl:qualifiedCardinality>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&Public_Contracting;hasAdjudicationCriterion"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="&Public_Contracting;Adjudication_Criterion"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&Public_Contracting;hasCPV"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="&Public_Contracting;CPV"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="&Public_Contracting;Procedure_Team"/>
        <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="&Public_Contracting;Proposal"/>
    </owl:Class>

 <!-- http://127.0.0.1/Public_Contracting.owl#CPV -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="&Public_Contracting;CPV">
        <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="&Public_Contracting;Candidature"/>
        <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="&Public_Contracting;Clarifications"/>
        <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="&Public_Contracting;Entity"/>
        <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="&Public_Contracting;Person"/>
        <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="&Public_Contracting;Procedure"/>
        <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="&Public_Contracting;Procedure_Team"/>
        <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="&Public_Contracting;Proposal"/>
    </owl:Class>
```

Comment: I guess it's a namespace problem: in your SPARQL query everything is in namespace `<http://127.0.0.1/Public_Contracting.owl#>`. Are you sure that is also the case in your ontology? for example in the ontology snippet you have `<hasCPV rdf:resource="&Public_Contracting;CPV1"/>`, but I'm not sure that the default namespace (used for hasCPV) is what you expect.

Comment: but the problem is filtering. If i remove last two setences from query i get public:Procedure_1 and public:Procedure_2. I can´t filter. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FILTER regex (?cpvp, "^CPV1")` is true is `?cpvp` starts with `CPV1`, but, if I'm not wrong, the values of `?cpvp` will start with the namespace string `&Public_Contracting;`. Try your query without the FILTER, and see what the values for `?cpvp` look like. Maybe you want to test if those values end with `CPV1`: in this case you should use `FILTER regex (?cpvp, "CPV1$")`.

---

Looking at your comments, it seems that you actually want to get all individuals of type `Procedure` linked with property `hasCPV` to a resource containing "CPV1". Then, you probably need this query (untested):

```
PREFIX ns: <http://127.0.0.1/Public_Contracting.owl#>
SELECT ?proc 
WHERE {
    ?proc a ns:Procedure ; 
          ns:hasCPV ?cpv.
    FILTER regex (STR(?cpv), "CPV1$")
}
```

Comment: If i delete filter, i get no results :(

Comment: but if i use "a" instead ns:CPV in last setence i get for proc|cpv|cpvp :public:Procedure_1 | public:CPV1 | public:CPV;  public:Procedure_1 | public:CPV1 | <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual>;  public:Procedure_2 | public:CPV2 | public:CPV;public:Procedure_2 | public:CPV2 | <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual>

Comment: You need to remove the ^ from your regex, and you need STR() around the other argument to REGEX. Regexes can only be applied to strings or plain literals.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to match a specific resource, identified by the URI `http://127.0.0.1/Public_Contracting.owl#CPV1`. Then the answer (or rather the query) is simpler:

```
PREFIX ns: <http://127.0.0.1/Public_Contracting.owl#>
SELECT ?proc 
WHERE {
  ?proc a ns:Procedure ; 
        ns:hasCPV ns:CPV1.
}
```

This selects each procedure that `hasCPV <http://127.0.0.1/Public_Contracting.owl#CPV1>`.